# Job Acceptance - Can the employer Rescind?

Tags: communication

I recently accepted a job, pending a two weeks notice to my present employer. I was at work the first week, but not the second as I was incredibly sick with what I believe was the flu, but I don't want to self-diagnose myself.

I was originally working through a temp agency, and now was hired with this new employer through a temp agency as a direct-hire. My question is, the temp agency that gave my information to the new employer has information that I did not attend my last week of work. I did inform the prior employer that I was ill on Monday and Tuesday, and told them I would not be in all week.

[Edit]
What can I do to prevent this from being a problem, since I do not have a Dr. note if this mis-information (one-sided) from the temp agency were to get to my new employer?

Comment: Hey jxrts, on Workplace Stack Exchange, our goal is to try to solve problems. I'd suggest editing the question to ask what you should do to prevent this from being a problem instead of having it be something you worry about. Right now, the answer could be "yes, it's a problem" but that doesn't really help you since it's not actionable. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I believe I worded the question to fit the rules a bit better.

Comment: Would me informing the new employer about my absence now be of benefit to me?

Comment: I'd say the answers are probably going to fall along the lines of "open and honest communications", but we'll see what the community has to say. :)

Comment: How is it misinformation? You _didn't_ attend work that week.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship note the `one-sided` in parenthesis. The information the temp agency had was only what they were told, and did not take into consideration the facts of what happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consequences of rescinding an offer of employment depends upon your contract (their offer) and local laws.  Most likely the only consequences for the employer is that they would then have to resume looking.  So, while I can't definitively answer the question, most likely it is "yes, yes they can".

So, on to what you can and should do about that.  I believe the answer is: nothing.

Not completing your notice period is only of concern to your new employer insofar as it reflects on your work ethics and probability of doing the same to them.

Either your new employer is concerned about this, in which case they either ask you to explain or they let you go without further communication.  In the first case, you gain nothing by proactively bringing it to their attention.  In the second case it **might** assuage their concern enough to keep your new job, but do you really want to work for a company that would let you go without question over such a minor matter? This isn't theft or interpersonal problems at work. At worst it is slightly unprofessional, but nothing major.  To dismiss you without discussing it and hearing what you say have to say about it -- nobody I would want to work for.